# difference between count_value(0) vs count_value(1) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Request:
data['Churn'].value_counts(0)

Output:

`0    7963`
`1    2037`

Request:
data['Churn'].value_counts(1)

Output:

`0    79.63`
`1    20.37`

Could you please explain how parameters of 1, 0 for  value_counts work?

Comment: Sorry, could not create a proper table. 0, 1 - are rows.

Comment: if you find the answer useful please mark it as accepted (gray tick besides the answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an answer when [reading documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
value_counts(0)
```

is the same as:

```
value_counts(normalize=0)
```

which is interpreted as:

```
value_counts(normalize=False)
```

While `1` is interpreted as `True` in the opposite case.

That's why.